# Using EPPlus Excel - How to ignore excel error checking or remove green tag on top left of the cell.(c#)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, epplus

EPPLus does not currently support disabling that green tag.

How to ignore excel error checking or remove green tag on top left of the cell.
While exporting the report to excel some of the column having number format giving the green tag having message "number stored as text".
How to fixed this issue.

I have tried this code but using this code  i am getting the error. Don't know how to fixed this error.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml;
     namespace OfficeOpenXml
     {
  public class ExcelIgnoredError : XmlHelper
  {
    private ExcelWorksheet _worksheet;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
      internal ExcelIgnoredError(XmlNamespaceManager ns, XmlNode node, 
     ExcelWorksheet xlWorkSheet) :
     base(ns, node)
      {
        _worksheet = xlWorkSheet;
      }

      public bool NumberStoredAsText
      {
        get
        {
            return GetXmlNodeBool("@numberStoredAsText");
        }
        set
        {
            SetXmlNodeBool("@numberStoredAsText", value);
        }
      }



    public bool TwoDigitTextYear
    {
        get
        {
            return GetXmlNodeBool("@twoDigitTextYear");
        }
        set
        {
            SetXmlNodeBool("@twoDigitTextYear", value);
        }
    }
    public string Range
    {
        get
        {
            return GetXmlNodeString("@sqref");
        }
        set
        {
            SetXmlNodeString("@sqref", value);
        }
    }
}

}
```

I am getting error as following

XMLHELPER DOESNOT CONTAINS CONSTRUCTOR THAT TAKES TWO ARGUMENT
THE NAME GetXmlNodeBool DOES NOT EXIST IN THE CURRENT CONTEXT
THE NAME SetXmlNodeBool DOES NOT ESIST IN THE CURRENT CONTEXT

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that tag. *Fix the error*. That tag appears when a numeric value is *forced* to look like a text field by prefixing it with `'`. It *won't* appear if you set the cell's style to text.

Comment: Post your code. Perhaps all you need to do is *remove* the `'` prefix and set the correct style

Comment: Yes that is correct .But what should i do if there is a number field?

Comment: Post your code. Don't force people to guess what you are talking about. Try various fixes in Excel itself, for example removing `'` from a field and selecting `Text` as its format will make it look like text without the green mark

Comment: Actually the value having number type is stored as text that's why i am getting the error .I also need to display the number value as number format type in excel and it works .It is displaying the number format but i am getting that green tag in cell.

Comment: I repeat, it's impossible to *guess* what your code does. Post your code or the question will have to be closed

Comment: Sorry I am not forcing any people.I only want some helpful suggestion to fixed the issue.

Comment: Impossible without the code

Comment: You can see i have updated my question with a code .

Comment: You haven't posted any relevant code. EPPlus doesn't deal with XML. It doesn't need XML namespaces. A simple `sheet.LoadFromCollection()` or `sheet.LoadFromDataReader()` are enough to fill a sheet and return a range that you can format or turn into a table. You didn't show anything that *sets* any fields.

Comment: You have to set the correct datatype for the cell. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209636/epplus-number-format/40214134#40214134

Comment: I already explained how to fix *your code's* error. Just *don't* add the prefix. *Don't* try to hack the number into appearing as text. Set the *cell's Format properties*.

Comment: @VDWWD please close this as a duplicate. I've already voted to close because the OP didn't provide any code that could be modified to set that style. BTW that's the format, not the data type but it doesn't really matter. The OP should try that and come back with any questions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you are right. Setting the format only works if the correct datatype is set. And i've flagged the question as a duplicate. that's all I can do.

Comment: @VDWWD good job pointing out that `Don't change the decimal and thousand separators to your own localization. Excel will do that for you.`. Attempting to "fix" decimals is a big source of bugs. Perhaps even *this* one?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an application setting (not a Workbook setting). So I think you can't do this through EPPlus.

Please see the following [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a0642211-abb9-4a37-b59e-4f3c3a5ac33a/how-do-i-turn-off-the-number-stored-as-text-warning?forum=excel) for more details.

Comment: So how to fix it?

Comment: @SourabhChoubey by fixing the actual error, if there is one. Post the code that produces the tag. Remember, the tag appears if you force a numeric value to appear as text by prefixing it with `'`

Comment: Is it possible to do it by the epplus c#. I have saw one solution to add ignoreexcel error class that will remove that error from excel but that class have some error.

Comment: @SourabhChoubey first, it's NOT an error. Second, the best way to remove the problem is to *not* put it there in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Panagiotis . Now its work for me by disabled the option of enable background checking error. But i want to do that by code.Let me put my code here .