# Formatting and overriding the default cell format of date & time while writing it in an Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, export-to-excel

We are capturing the entire table data inside the `$("#dvtablerptTDetails")[0].innerHTML` containing all the data and the same will be saved in the session and later converted to string & sent to `Response.Write()` that would later create an Excel file containing data of filetype xlsx

Here the requirement is to override the default cell format when writing the data, especially for the date & time format of an individual cell.

By default, when saved and viewed, 
 Cell Format will be in **`dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`** 
But Expected Cell Format should be in **`dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`**

So tried to modify data prefixing and suffixing with Dot(`.`) or At the rate(`@`). But it worked printing as per our requirement. But unable to escape special characters. Since it writes exactly as it is.

Below here is the partial snippets

```
DateTimeUtility objDTU = new DateTimeUtility();
RegisteredDate = objDTU.GetActualDateTime((DateTime)(dsTestcener.Rows[i]["TestApprovedDate"])).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

public DateTime GetActualDateTime(DateTime utcDateTime)
{
    DateTime actualDateTime;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserTimeZone"] != null)
    {
        actualDateTime = utcDateTime.AddHours(Double.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserTimeZone"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    else
    {
        actualDateTime = utcDateTime;
    }
    return actualDateTime;

}
```

Tried to modify the above data assigned to `RegisteredDate` object

> ```
> objDTU.GetActualDateTime((DateTime)(dsTestcener.Rows[i]["TestApprovedDate"]))
> .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
> ```

- Actual Data(html) : 28-Feb-2020 15:14:38
- Actual Data(xsl)  : 28/02/2020 15:14
- Expected Data(xsl): 28-Feb-2020 15:14:38

> ```
> objDTU.GetActualDateTime((DateTime)(dsTestcener.Rows[i]["TestApprovedDate"]))
> .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
> ```

- Actual Data(html) : 28-Feb-2020 15:14:38.313
- Actual Data(xsl)  : 14:38.
- Expected Data(xsl): 28-Feb-2020 15:14:38.313

> ```
> objDTU.GetActualDateTime((DateTime)(dsTestcener.Rows[i]["TestApprovedDate"]))
> .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
> ```

- Actual Data(html) : 28-Feb-2020 15:14:38
- Actual Data(xsl)  : 28/02/2020 15:14:38
- Expected Data(xsl): 28-Feb-2020 15:14:38

---

The below coding snippets shows how does the html data get captured & traversed to `Response.Write()`

```
function ExportAnalysis() {
    try {
        var batchDetails = $("#displayDetails").html();
        var message = JSON.stringify({ BatchDetails: batchDetails });
        CallAjaxJSON(message, '<%=Request.ApplicationPath%>' + "/MES/TestCentre.aspx/PersistBatchDetails", OnExportBatchSuccess, OnFailure);
        var url = '<%=Context.Request.ApplicationPath%>' + '/MES/ExportToExcel.aspx?name=Analysis Response';
        window.open(url);

    } catch (e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string PersistBatchDetails(object BatchDetails)
{
    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["DashboardBatchInfo"] = BatchDetails;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}
    return "S001";
}
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = "Excel";
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["name"]))
        fileName = Request.QueryString["name"];
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string BatchDetails = Convert.ToString(Session["DashboardBatchInfo"]);
    Response.Write(BatchDetails);
    Response.End();
    Session["DashboardBatchInfo"] = null;
}
```

---

How should we need to achieve in writing the expected data in the respective format?

Comment: Use [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209636/epplus-number-format/40214134#40214134). It looks like you are just exporting a html string as xls

Answer (score 0):

**Finally found the solution:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string PersistBatchDetails(object BatchDetails)
{
    try
    {
        string pattern = @"\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}|\d{2}\-[a-zA-Z]{3}\-\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
        var res = r.Replace(BatchDetails.ToString(), new MatchEvaluator(ConvertDateFormat));
        HttpContext.Current.Session["DashboardBatchInfo"] = res;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        BasePage objBasePage = new BasePage();
        objBasePage.Log.LogError("Page: TestActivation, Method: GetBatchesList " + ex.Message, ex);
        objBasePage = null;
        return "S002";
    }
    return "S001";
}

public static string ConvertDateFormat(Match m)
{
    var mydate = DateTime.Parse(m.Value);
    return string.Format("=\"{0}\"", mydate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
}
```