# Importing csv file into Excel using EPPlus losing trailing zeroes on data

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using C# and EPPlus to import `.csv` data into a workbook. My only issue is that after the import into Excel, I am losing trailing zeroes on the data.

For example:

- in the `.CSV` file, the data is this:  1250.80
- in the `.xlsx` file, the data ends up being  1250.8

Seems minor but I need this to compare workbook to workbook and not see all of these diffs.

Here is the read routine

```
string[] csvInputfile = File.ReadAllLines(filePathName);
```

Here is how I am trying to put double quotes around the data

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < csvInputfile.Length; idx++)
{
    csvInputfile[idx] = csvInputfile[idx].Replace(",", ",\"");
}
```

Here I am writing the contents to the Excel instance

```
for (int i = 0; i < csvInputfile.Length; i++)
{
    ExcelWorksheet curWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(csvInputfile[outerLoopCnt]);

    for (int j = 0; j < csvInputfile.Length; j++)
    {
        innerLoopCnt++;

        curWorksheet.Cells[j + 1, 1, j + 1, 100].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
        curWorksheet.Cells[j + 1, 1].LoadFromText(csvInputfile[innerLoopCnt], format);

        if (csvInputfile[innerLoopCnt + 1] == "")
        {
            outerLoopCnt = innerLoopCnt + 2;
            innerLoopCnt += 2;

            break;
        }
    }

    if (innerLoopCnt == csvInputfile.Length) 
    {
        break; 
    }
}
```

Here I save the file:

```
excelPackage.SaveAs(file);
```

This is the general idea and its not working very well. This is a crude approach but I'm not sure how else to make this work, I would appreciate any help

Comment: Try to set numeric format for columns with numbers https://stackoverflow.com/a/40214134/7357322

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, however, you should be able to directly open the CSV file from Excel. Excel can read CSV files and gives you the option to set the delimiters. It just appears to me that you are re-inventing the wheel unnecessarily.